# childNodes - whitespace inside elements

Tags: javascript, html, whitespace

```
<div id="myDIV">
<p>First p element (index 1)</p>
<p>Second p element (index 3)</p>
</div>
```

Trying to understand why index 0 is a text node.

According to this example from w3schools, index 0, 2, & 4 are text nodes.  Index 1 & 3 are p elements.

Is index 0 a text node because it is whitespace? If so, where does this whitespace exist? Between the opening div tag and first opening p tag?

Comment: The text nodes are `\n` in your html. And yes, it is between `<div id="myDIV">` and `<p>`.
So, in order not to have these `\n` as textNodes, just put together all your html, like this: 
`<div id="myDIV"><p>First p element (index 1)</p><p>Second p element (index 3)</p></div>`

Comment: Check this [bin](http://jsbin.com/sicojon/edit?html,js)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Line breaks are whitespace, too. If you put those elements on a single line, you can omit whitespaces.

```
<div id="myDIV"><p>First p element (index 0)</p><p>Second p element (index 1)</p></div>
```

### EDIT

The index numbers in the question, as well as in my answer, are **node** indices. One can use them EG. using the [`childNodes` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_childnodes.asp).

On the other hand, one can use **element** indices, that do not count text and comment nodes, EG by accessing the [`childern` property](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_children.asp).